# How to return an array in a recursive function?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, recursion, mergesort

I am a C begginer I was trying to code a merge_sort function. I wrote my code below.

variable "array_global" is the merge between array "a" and array "b", and all that merge proccess works fine, the problem occurs when the function returns "array global", since it seems that it only returns the first element of the array.

For example, if "array_global" is [19, 26], integer pointer "a" which receives the result of the function only receives [19]

What did I did wrong?
And why this happens?

Thx in advance

```
int *merge_sort(int array[], int len)
{
  if (len == 1)
  {
    return array;
  }
  else
  {
    int l1 = (len/2);
    int l2 = len - l1;
    int sub_array_1[l1]; int sub_array_2[l2];
    for (int i = 0; i<l1; i++)
    {
      sub_array_1[i] = array[i];
    }
    for (int i = l1; i<len; i++)
    {
      sub_array_2[i-l1] = array[i];
    }
    int *a = merge_sort(sub_array_1, l1);//Receives array_global value
    int a_size = (sizeof(a)/sizeof(int));
    int *b = merge_sort(sub_array_2, l2);//Receives array_global value
    int b_size = (sizeof(b)/sizeof(int));
    int mult = a_size + b_size;
    int *array_global = malloc(sizeof(*array_global)*mult);
    merge(a, b, a_size, b_size, array_global);
    return array_global;

  }
}
```

Comment: You've got yourself a bunch of memory leaks in here, as in every recursion step, you allocate a temporary array which you never deallocate.

Comment: How are you determining that the result only contains `[19]`?

Comment: You can do the entire sort **in place** (i.e., storing the output in the input array). Subsequently, the function doesn't need to return anything.

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb: If you can write a merge sort in place I want to know about it. This is one of the few algorithms for which the book shows a copy. Note that you need only one extra buffer and can oscillate.

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb Is it possible to free memory allocated in a pointer if it is passed as a parameter of another function? I was thinking about freeing the pointer "array_global" inside "merge" function but idk if it is possible. I was also wondering, if you do not return any value, you cannot do a recursive function or not?

Comment: @jarmod I tried the merge_sort with array [26, 19, 100, 89] and printed out array global to check the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mistake here:

`int a_size = (sizeof(a)/sizeof(int));`

should read

`int a_size = l1;`

`sizeof` doesn't measure the size of an array on the heap.

Memory leak here:

```
return array_global;
```

should be:

```
free(a);
free(b);
return array_global;
```

Comment: But there is still a memory leak with array_global right? Is there a way in which you can free that pointer?

Comment: @Luigi_S_R: The initial caller of `merge_sort` needs to deal with that. Typically merge sorts are used where a copy is wanted in the first place.